# How to configure page not found error in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, webserver

Can we Configure any page to be displayed instead of `page not found` error page in tomcat.
If yes then How ??

Answer (score 1):

Declare an `<error-page>` in `web.xml` wherein you can specify the page which should be displayed on a certain Throwable (or any of its subclasses) or a HTTP status code. E.g.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

which will display the error page on any subclass of the `java.lang.Exception`

or,

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

which will display the error page on a HTTP 404 error,

Also refer [HTTP Error Codes List](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp)